# IBDesignable and prepareForInterfaceBuilder for NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

I am subclassing `NSLayoutConstraint` to provide custom spacing depending on a flag. Is it possible to have this reflected in the Interface Builder? I tried using `IBDesignable` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, but it has no effect on the `NSLayoutConstraint` in the Interface Builder (only at runtime does it reflect).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var doubleConstant: Bool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        handleSelection()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        handleSelection()
    }

    func handleSelection() {
        if doubleConstant {
            constant *= 2
        }
    }
}
```

I have a flag in `IBInspectable` that will double the constant at runtime if set. Is there a way for this to be reflected in the StoryBoard so it's clear something will be happening?

Comment: Any updates on this?